# Enum Changed Event

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am writing a WPF application and I would like to use an Enum for a State variable.

Example: When the program start up certain controls are disabled until the state changes.

When the state changes I would like to disable/enable a variety of controls via an event handler.  I have written plenty of custom event handlers in the past, however, using an enum as the trigger has managed to blow my mind.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using an MVVM approach then I agree with Daniel White that you need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged. You should bind the IsEnabled member on your controls to a property on your ViewModel.

Code:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
      public MyEnum EnumValue 
      { 
           get { return enumValue; } 
           set { 
                 enumValue = value;
                 AreControlsEnabled = enumValue == MyEnum.SomeValue;
           }
      }

      public bool AreControlsEnabled 
      {
           get { return areControlsEnabled; }
           set {
                 areControlsEnabled = value;
                 if (PropertyChanged != null)
                     PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArg("AreControlsEnabled");
            }
      }

      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

XAML:

```
<TextBox IsEnabled="{Binding AreControlsEnabled}"/>
```

Comment: Based on the complexity of the application I think i will simply code a few methods to toggle the controls.  Far from elegant, but not worth the level of abstraction of MVVM or similar design patterns.  Thanks!

Comment: @Ritz Beware the "my app is too simple for MVVM" trap! Apps often grow in complexity as spec changes and when that happens the sooner you have MVVM in place the better.  Even for the most basic apps there is no real overhead for a basic MVVM implimentation and it simplifies the overall structure of your app and will enable you to move forward.

Comment: Grumble Grumble Grumble.  Very reasonable.  Perhaps I shall do so now to prevent myself from having to so so later when it has gotten bigger.  I doubt it will grow but... you never know.

Answer (score 3):

You should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your view model and invoke the event when the value changed.

Comment: I was hoping to to have to abstract things out that far.  This is a relatively simple implementation.  If no other options are suggested then I shall =D